# ValueError: shapes (313,8) and (79,8) not aligned: 8 (dim 1) != 79 (dim 0)

Tags: python

```
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

#get file
dataset_path = keras.utils.get_file("auto-mpg.data", "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data")
column_names = ['MPG','Cylinders','Displacement','Horsepower','Weight','Acceleration', 'Model Year', 'Origin']
raw_dataset = pd.read_csv(dataset_path, names=column_names, na_values = "?", comment='\t', sep=" ", skipinitialspace=True)

#delete miss data
dataset = raw_dataset.copy()
dataset = dataset.dropna()

target = dataset[['MPG']]
xdata = dataset[['Cylinders','Displacement','Horsepower','Weight','Acceleration', 'Model Year', 'Origin']]
def train66(dset,target):
    # add cons
    dataset_ = sm.add_constant(dset, has_constant = "add")

    #split
    X = dataset_
    y = target
    train_x2, test_x2, train_y2, test_y2 = train_test_split(X,y, train_size = 0.8, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 1)

    # reg fit
    fit_train2 = sm.OLS(train_y2,train_x2)

    #mse
    mse1 = mean_squared_error(y_true = test_y2, y_pred = fit_train2.predict(test_x2))
    
    return mse1

print(train66(xdata,target))
```

i using this code but, i dont know what is wrong

Error:ValueError: shapes (313,8) and (79,8) not aligned: 8 (dim 1) != 79 (dim 0)

i did the same thing possible without function but in function it does not work

Comment: Please add more details about your problem, maybe the full stack trace of the error, and what is the data you're using (it's shape mainly)